# When does a service locator method become more prefered?

Tags: design-patterns, factory-pattern

To realize the Inversion of Control, one can use either a service locator or a dependency injector. Service Locator may be harder to or lengthier to code than DI. 
I think the Service Locator is like another name for Factory pattern, right ? And I don't know when I must use the SL instead of DI ? Do you any real cases to apply any of them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a default position, avoid ServiceLocators.  See Mark Seemann's [excellent blog post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx) on the subject.

Dependency Injection is much easier to maintain, and does not require a "injector", or DI framework at all.  It's just a matter or providing an object with it's dependencies (preferably in the constructor) rather than letting the object gather them itself.  I am a pretty strict adherent to DI, and I almost never use a DI framework.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are subtil differences between SL and Factory pattern.

In general the factory pattern will create a new instance of the service and the caller became the owner of the instance.

On the other hand, the service locator will provide a pre-existing instance of the service. The caller don't became the "owner" of this instance. Such *pre-existing instance* is often shared between all clients.
Most of the time the responsibility to instantiate the *pre-existing instance* is left to some third party code.